# JSON and boolean values

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid (jquery plugin), and using json format to return the results from server side. I have 'yes' or 'no' values from the database. But when displaying, jqgrid displays them as 'true' or 'false'. How can I keep the values as 'Yes' or 'No'?

Thanks

Comment: Could you include in your question the definition of the column from the `colModel`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't include neither the definition of the jqGrid column having the problem nor any test JSON data. So I try to tip. I suppose, that you save the information in the database as boolean and send the values 'true' and 'false' inside of JSON data. If you don't use any formatter, the data will be displayed as text. To display the data as another text you can use ['select' formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#formatter_type_select):

```
formatter:'select', stype:'select', edittype:'select',
editoptions: { value: "false:No;true:Yes" }
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's about the display options, you can use a checkbox and EditOptions for this field in jqGrid.

```
editoptions: { value:"Yes:No" }
```

[http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules)

Comment: I just want to display those values. I do not need the checkbox.

Comment: How are you adding the columns to the grid ? You probably have to write a little custom function that returns yes when true and no when false.